# Java Random Access File strange characters

Tags: java, file, randomaccessfile

So I am using the following code to write to a file in Java, the text prints fine, but it has strange characters between the letters.

```
public static void foo() throws IOException{
    static RandomAccessFile configFile;
    configFile.writeChars("#Minecraft server properties");
    configFile.close();
}
```

[image]

I was searching for answer and everything pointed to incorrect usage of writeUTF() so I decided to try that instead which semi-fixed the issue, but I still have that character at the beginning of the line.

```
public static void foo() throws IOException{
    static RandomAccessFile configFile;
    configFile.writeUTF("#Minecraft server properties");
    configFile.close();
}
```

[image]

My questions are: what is that char? Vim shows it as an `@` and what can I do to remove it?

Comment: It's a length word. See the  Javadoc. To remove it, don't use `writeUTF()`. Don't use `writeUTF()` unless you are also going to use `readUTF()` to read it.

Comment: `writeChars()` is writing UTF-16. *Why* are you using `RandomAccessFile` and not `FileWriter`?

Comment: If you want to write human-readable text then RandomAccessFile is a bad choice.

Comment: @Andreas I was using RandomAccessFile because originally I wanted to read part of the file and insert something in the middle of it, but I think I'm just going to write the entire file

Answer (score 0):

That char is related with the encoding of the file you are creating.

Try using the following code instead:

```
public static void createConfigFile() throws IOException {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("PATH_TO_YOUR_CONFIG_FILE", false);
    writer.append("#Minecraft server properties");
    // Append any other content you need here.
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

Hope that helps!